Can embedding be tackled efficiently using MapReduce?
Embedding is necessary to convert text in vectors that are more tractable by machine learning models.
Can embedding be carried out (efficiently) using the MapReduce approach?
I suspect so: projecting text in another space shouldn't be much harder than relational algebra operations such as joins, which can be done efficiently using MapReduce.
Is there any source on this?

it's literally just a map, but you need to share the dictionary across workers, which might be expensive

@Alberto I'm aware that MR is essentially Turing-complete, so anything can be done using MR. My question is whether or not a distributed MR-style embedding is advantageous.

I see, you are probably looking for this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08495
